# Kiosk mode AIR desktop application

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am developing a photo capturing kiosk application on AIR as3 for Windows Desktop.
I have set the stage display to FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE and that works fine. (I have also hid the Start Menu and Task Bar)

The problem is if there is any pop-up like Windows Update or Team Viewer connection etc. it comes to the top in front of my application and then people are able to minimize my application and breach into my windows computer.

Can I do anything to make sure that my application ALWAYS STAYS ON TOP of all other messages, programs and applications ?

Comment: If I remember correctly, it is possible without using fullscreen mode : using a chromeless window (`NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE`), and setting `NativeWindow.alwaysInFront` to true. A bit of `orderToFront()` may be needed too. Not sure, and I don't have my tools on hand right now. That said, what use would have Team Viewer on a kiosk ? And why not disable windows updates on said kiosk ?

Comment: @Aralicia is right, just disable anything that will bother you in windows. If you are interested there are commercial solutions such as Zinc thatgive more power control http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/

Comment: @Aralicia Disabling Windows Update is not good advice. Also, I can see why Team Viewer would be installed (to save sending a tech out when something needs to be installed etc).

Comment: @Aralicia - Thanks a lot. Your solution worked for me. (I know its very late but then better late then never :P)